# Tomcat Unable to compile class for JSP in Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, tomcat7

I have created Servlet with this archetype: http://maciejwalkowiak.github.io/servlet3-maven-archetype/

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.maciejwalkowiak \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=servlet3-webapp-archetype \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.1
```

then I add index.jsp into src/main/webapp directory

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello, world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run `mvn tomcat7:run` and open http://127.0.0.1/mycontext/index.jsp

this error occurs:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

what is the problem?

## Update

I'm using java8 but I have following maven-compiler configuration in my maven:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Try cleaning your project.

Comment: mvn clean, but not solved

Answer (score 2):

You should double check your Tomcat version. Tomcat 7.0.32 contains a jar that is not fully compatible with Java 8, so upgrading your Tomcat version might help. Take a look at [this](http://www.howopensource.com/2015/07/unable-to-compile-class-for-jsp-the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved/).

Comment: Alternatively, you could also try upgrading to the ecj-4.2.2.jar alone.

Answer (score 1):

Which JDK are you using? If it's 8 you will have to update Tomcat to 8 as well. If that's not the case, you should try going to the Project menu and select Clean... from there. Then try also cleaning the Server and the Server Working folder by selecting these options from the right click menu.

Comment: see my updated question. I'm using maven-compiler plugin for using java 7

Comment: Did you also try to clean it?

Comment: I still think that the problem is the compatibility between Tomcat and Java 8... This error is usually due to the fact that there is a java.util.Map dependency somewhere in the code for JSP... And this was changed in Java 8. If it doesn't bother you and you're not compelled to use Tomcat 7, do you mind trying to upgrade it? So we will know for sure if that's the problem or if this error is caused by something else...

Comment: I've downgrade my java version to 1.7 but the problem persist. for upgrading tomcat I need tomcat8-maven-plugin but the 8 version doesn't exist.

Comment: Try adding this to the page: <%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>